# moviepy - cut every second frame from videoclip

Tags: python, python-3.x, video-processing, moviepy

I am making a .mp4 video clip using moviepy. Broadly speaking, it is a visualization of numerical simulation, that has some fixed time step. Every frame is calculated from previous after that time step. All calculations are carried out in numpy and frames are made using matplotlib. The overall duration of a clip is 90 seconds with 120 fps, and the image in clip change very slow (which is bad in terms of visual aspects). When I increase the time step, the numerical solution rapidly gets unstable.

Is there another way to speed up the clip?

P.S. I came up with the only idea - replacing every second frame from the clip. (haven't found any built-in moviepy function for this purpose)

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just speed it up with [`speedx(2)`](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.speedx.html#moviepy-video-fx-all-speedx)?

Comment: Brilliant.. it definetely worked. This speedx use fl_time that i've been trying to apply but it didn't work properly: newclip = clip.fl_time(lambda t: factor * t, apply_to=['mask', 'audio'])